# SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver

Tags: postgresql

Could you please help me for PostgreSQL error.
we are  getting the PostgreSQL error

```
remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

due to crossing the limit that is 115 by default. We do not want to increase the DB connection limit size. By executing the query

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity p WHERE p.datname = 'abc'
```

I noticed that numbers of connection are increasing automatically where the query column It have

```
SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'
```

Could you please help me how to stop automatically increasing the connections so that it will not show any PostgreSQL error "remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections".

Our application is running in the IBM cloud code engine, and the database is running in IBM cloud PostgreSQL.

Comment: You are opening database sessions, but never closing them. This is a bug in your application code. You must fix that bug.